# When a hydrogen atom absorbs a photon, what happens to the photon?

Tags: photons, atomic-physics

When a hydrogen atom absorbs a photon, what happens to the photon?
I know what happens afterward, but what exactly happens to the photon?

Comment: The photon disappears, its energy changing the bound state of the atom, raising it to an excited state. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html

Comment: All we know is that it disappears, whatever it was in the first place.

Comment: The SM gives us rules for the conditions under which fundamental particles can be created, destroyed, transmuted, or have their properties (e.g. kinetic energy or frequency, or vector direction) changed while remaining the same particle. A photon's energy is conserved, as is its momentum, through a transfer to the hydrogen atom, but its "photo-ness" is annihilated and ceases to be. Note that while the net number of quarks less anti-quarks (baryon number) and leptons less anti-leptons (lepton number) is conserved, there is no "photon number". The number of photons in the cosmos isn't conserved.

Comment: @ohwilleke, that's much more an answer than a comment.

Comment: After somebody hears your word, what happens to your word?

Answer (score 1):

What happens, is that the photon gets absorbed by the atom, and the absorbing electron moves to a higher energy level as per QM. You are asking what happens to the photon. The photon ceases to exist.

The photon transfers all its energy to the kinetic energy of the absorbing electron, and the photon ceases to exist. Its energy will be transformed into the kinetic energy of the electron.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer comes from the quantum electrodynamics:

A fermion in a bound state can absorb (emit) a "real" photon corresponding to excitation (de-excitation) of it and the photon completely disappears (appears).

But, a free fermion can't absorb (Compton scattering occurs), or emit, a "real" photon, because this would violate a conservation law ( conservation of energy, or\and conservation of momentum).

On the other hand, a free fermion can absorb, or emit, a "virtual" photon, which is off-shell. A free fermion can do this because off-shell virtual photons are not bound by the energy-momentum relations that apply to "real" photons that are on-shell.

Comment: I have proposed an edit to your post that is intended to be purely an edit of spelling, punctuation and grammar. There was a least one place (the "Compton scatter occurs" phrase), where the sentence could be read in a couple of possible ways in the original and I attempted to choose the reading that seemed most faithful to what you were intending to say. This is intended to be a friendly edit and I apologize if I have offended you by doing so, or if I have misconstrued something that you were trying to say. I appreciate your contribution and answer.

Comment: @ohwilleke Thanks a lot. I was a bit silly in writing this answer.